# React, Axios, Bluebird - CancelToken showing warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios, bluebird

I'm getting a warning in a React component that uses axios and a CancelToken to cancel any request onComponentWillUnmount. We are using Bluebird as global Promise.

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
}

axios.get(url, { cancelToken: this.cancelTokenSource.token })
    .then((response) => {
        response && response.data && this.setState({ title: response.data.title })
    })
```

Warning message:

bluebird.js?f684:1564 Warning: a promise was created in a handler at webpack-internal:// but was not returned from it, see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it

at new Promise (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js:2663:10)

at new CancelToken (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js:17:18)

at Function.source (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js:48:15)

at Component.componentDidMount (webpack-internal:///./app/index.tsx:131:87)

Comment: Posted code doesn't contain Bluebird. Are you using Bluebird as global Promise?

Comment: @estus, that is used internally in axios

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm positive Axios doesn't depend on Bluebird. Considering that ES6 promises are already there, this would be very awkward, especially for client-side package.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, yes, we are using Bluebird as global Promise.